# alt attribute undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Edit*
The original post was changed to another topic.

I get a `undefined` when I try to print the `alt` attribute using `innerHTML`

This [code](https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/2bkkr6g6/3/) by Gerardo Furtado, shows how it's working with a eventListener. I tried to use it in a function which I call in a condition:

```
function showName() {
  const altText = this.alt;
  text.innerHTML = altText;
}
```

condition:

```
if (isMatch === true) {
    applause.play();
    showName();
    removeOverlayHidden();
    setTimeout(function () {
    }, 1000);
  }
```

But while it is working with click listeners, it's not working anymore when used like above. Any idea I could solve this? I already tried several things.

Comment: Please make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is `this` in your context? You need an [mre] because how your code is called is important part of the behavior of `this` keyword. Which is often confusing when coming from other OOP languages

Comment: What does "it's not working anymore" mean? Do you receive an error? Is `isMatch` really _true_?

Comment: The example would be here > http://jsfiddle.net/kindasport/ea4z0s1h/26/
Yes the condition turns true as the audio and removeOverlayHidden(); is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `this` in recursive functions. In your event listener `this` may return the clicked element but in `showName()` it will only return a `window` object, which is not what you want.

So you will need to store `this` and pass it to all related functions. There are several ways of how to do this. In the code below, I am just passing `this` with a parameter, which is `that`.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".memory-card");
let firstCard, secondCard;
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;

const text = document.getElementById("show-name");
const myImage = document.querySelectorAll(".front-face");


function showName(that) {
  const altText = that.querySelector('.back-face').alt;
  text.innerHTML = altText;
}


function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;
  // flipCardSound();
  this.classList.add("flip");

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    // first card click
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }

  // second card click
  hasFlippedCard = false;
  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch(this);
}


function checkForMatch(that) {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;

  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();


  if (isMatch === true) {
    // applause.play(); // plays audio file when cards do match
    // removeOverlayHidden(); // Adds a blurry dark background
    showName(that); //returns "undefined"
    setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
  }
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener("click", flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener("click", flipCard);
  // resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove("flip");
    secondCard.classList.remove("flip");

    resetBoard();
  }, 1500);
}

cards.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener("click", flipCard));
```

```css
.memory-game {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(16% - 10px);
  height: calc(16% - 10px);
  margin: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00e6a0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#show-name {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 2%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
 <section class="memory-game">
   <div class="memory-card" data-framework="regula">
     <img class="front-face" src="img/people/regula.png" alt="Regula" />
     <img class="back-face" src="img/question.svg" alt="Question Badge" />
   </div>
   <div class="memory-card" data-framework="regula">
     <img class="front-face" src="img/people/regula.png" alt="Regula" />
     <img class="back-face" src="img/question.svg" alt="Question Badge" />
   </div>
 </section>

 <div id="show-name"></div>
```

However, you are using `const altText = this.alt;`. Even if `this` was correct, that wouldn't work since in your case `this` is just the parent element. I have just replaced it with `const altText = that.querySelector('.back-face').alt;`.